# subtract the full url after the hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash, location

i want to load my pages on my website with AJAX and jQuery. It works fine but the url's looks

***http://mywebsite.com/#mywebsite.com/thepage***

i want to subtract the url so it looks like

***http://mywebsite.com/#thepage***

i hope someone know how to do that. This is the code:

```
if(window.location.hash) {

} else {
  window.location="#THE_FULL_URL";
}

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#wrapper"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#wrapper"),
    $el;

$("a").live("click", function(event){
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    var hash = location.hash;
    document.title = ( hash.replace(/^.*#/, '') || 'blank' ) + '.';

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find(".content")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " .content", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn();
                    fix();
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way in Java using regex:

```
String url = "http://mywebsite.com/#mywebsite.com/thepage";
String newUrl = url.replaceAll("^(http://)([^#]*)#\\2(.*)$", "$1$2#$3"));
```

And here it is in Javascript:

```
var url = "http://mywebsite.com/#mywebsite.com/thepage";
var newUrl = url.replace(/^(http:\/\/)([^#]*)#\2(.*)$/g, "$1$2#$3");
```

Comment: Just replace the `url` variable in my `url.replace..` statement above with your variable.